# SSIS: Same Script different packages: Error: Cannot run on this edition of Integration Services. Execute Out of Process?

Tags: ssis

I have one package that calls two other child packages.  All three packages have the exact same script task at the top.  The script task executes in the parent package and the first child package, however the last child package breaks on the script task with the error

The task "script task" cannot run on this edition of Integration Services. It requires a higher level edition.

If I disable the script task in the last package, it executes the task fine.

I haven't tried running this package by itself because it would be a pain to setup, and it runs fine if I disable this script task, though I may need to try and see if that works.

I imagine it is related to Execute Out of Process?  Why would this cause an issue for the script task?  It is very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the following links. Hopefully, they might help you with the issue that you are facing.

1. [**SSIS Execute Package with Execute out of Process = True causes ProductLevelToLow error**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/86e4071d-e018-4618-91f1-08016bbc6391/)
2. [**SSIS: Should you execute child packages in-process or out-of-process?**](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/05/16/1414.aspx)

Comment: This is helpful and maybe there is no solution.  I forgot to add that this issue only occurs in BIDS, not when calling the parent package with dtexec on another server.  I use Out of Process to have 4 packages running asynchronously together.